# js and css on-demand loading

Tags: php, javascript, css, kohana

i am confused by the concept of on-demand loading

I saw this blog [post](http://syedgakbar.wordpress.com/2007/11/17/on-demand-loading-of-javascript-and-css-files/) and was wondering if I could do the same with php using the ff. approach:

1. check current url
2. serve css or js based on current url

which may be done like this in Kohana

```
if (uri::segment(1) == 'search') // check current url
echo html::stylesheet('search.css'); // serve stylesheet
echo html::script('search.js'); // serve script
endif;
```

or am I getting the idea wrong?

a side question would be is ti alright to have a css file for each individual page aside from the site-wide forms.css and layout.css

Comment: http://syedgakbar.wordpress.com/ is marked private by its owner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use your approach. css files are better served in the head and so you can put your conditions in the site wide template.

for javascript, which should be served at the bottom of your html, you can simply put your  tags directly in your application/view/your_action.php without using any url based condition.

about

> would be is ti alright to have a css
>   file for each individual page aside
>   from the site-wide forms.css and
>   layout.css

well, you can do it but keep in mind that this will generate an extra request (for the css files) for every new page visited by the user. if performance is critical you'd better serve a unique compressed css.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for HTML and PHP using REQUEST_URI. the variable will hold the page you're at, you might want to do some parsing of it to get the exact page with out slashes etc, it's usually a relative path to the document from the root.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Demo</title>
<?php

switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
    case "/home.php":
        echo '<link type="text/css" href="home.css" rel="stylesheet" />';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/home.js"></script>';
    break;

    case "/about.php":
        echo '<link type="text/css" href="about.css" rel="stylesheet" />';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/about.js"></script>';
    break;

    case "/contact.php":
        echo '<link type="text/css" href="contact.css" rel="stylesheet" />';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact.js"></script>';
    break;

    default :
        echo '<link type="text/css" href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" />';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/default.js"></script>';
    break;
}
?>
</head>

<body>
My Page
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you will do if you have 30 pages? Would it be 30 cases in that switch? This is classical indian code. You know you can avoid that swich with something like '<link type="text/css" href="' . $page . '.css" rel="stylesheet" />';